Taking backup of a large database that writes nearly 20 GB of data every day
as I mentioned in the title, how should I back up a 10 TB PostgreSQL database to which a lot of data is written every day?
If I need to give a little more detail, the data I mentioned is partitioned and there is a partition for each month. There is approximately 400 GB of data for each month. In this case, it is impossible to take a backup every day with pg_dump. In this case, I tried to use pgbackrest to take an incremental backup, but although approximately 20 GB of data is written every day, it uses 500 GB for the changing data, and this creates a lot of traffic and I/O events inside. What kind of policy should I create to take a backup of such a large database?

Are you using block-level incremental backups? With databases of that size, it's usually more efficient to use volume snapshots, if your storage supports that.

What are the restoration requirements?

@mustaccio Yes, I am currently taking block-based incremental backups as you said, but I am not sure how reliable the backups taken this way are.

@jjanes The RTO value is 12 hour approximately and the RPO value is 8 hour approximately

How long does it take to replay one days worth of WAL?

@jjanes I've never tried to do this before. How can I do it and what should I pay attention to?

I'm not really sure as I've not studied pgbackrest much.  I've used pgbarman, or just did my backups and restoration by hand. The gist of it though is that you do a basebackup and keep a WAL archive, both of which pgbackrest can probably automate for you, then you restore by restoring the base backup and rolling it forward using the archive.  Then instead of taking a new base backup once every RPO, you instead need to take one every time the WAL replay take too long to fit in a RTO, which is hopefully much less.
